# Manual date entry validation for jQuery UI Datepicker maxDate option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have jQuery datepicker on a page that needs to allow manual entry of the date, but also needs to validate that the date is no more than one day ahead.  The picker control has been limited via the maxDate, but when one manually enters the date, they can enter a date more than one day ahead.  How does one (me) stop that?  Here is what I have so far:

```
$(".datepicker").attr("placeholder", "mm-dd-yyyy").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    maxDate: "+1",
    showOtherMonths: true
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the above answer is correct, but it  does not validate the form, the user still will be able to submit the form,

I have done some researches, but could not find ny, finally I wrote this function which works fine and validate the form, and does not let submit the form until the correct date is entered, Hope it helps!

The only thing you need to do is add this code, and then this will be applied to all the fields with 'datePicker' class.

```
 $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: Date.parse("1900-01-01"),
            maxDate: Date.parse("2100-01-01"),
            yearRange: "c-90:c+150"
        });

        // validation in case user types the date out of valid range from keyboard : To fix the bug with out of range date time while saving in sql 
        $(function () {
            $.validator.addMethod(
                "date",
                function (value, element) {

                    var minDate = Date.parse("1900-01-01");
                    var maxDate = Date.parse("2100-01-01");
                    var valueEntered = Date.parse(value);

                    if (valueEntered < minDate || valueEntered > maxDate) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(minDate));
                },
                "Please enter a valid date!"
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure if datepicker fires an event if the control's value is changed by typing in directly. You can bind a function to the `.change()` event:

```
$(".datepicker").attr("placeholder", "mm-dd-yyyy").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",                 // since you have defined a mask
    maxDate: "+1",
    showOn: "button",
    showOtherMonths: true

}).on("change", function(e) {
    var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    var maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 1); // add one day
    maxDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);           // clear time portion for correct results
    if (curDate > maxDate) {
        alert("Invalid date");
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", maxDate);
    }
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4Bt/)

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same requirement and here is the solution that worked for me like a charm:

```
  $(".datepicker").attr("placeholder", "mm-dd-yyyy").change(function(){
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
  }).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      maxDate: "+1",
      showOtherMonths: true
  });
```

Modified fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hs84yk7m/1/) referenced from Salman A's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229630/1403118)

Comment: Works nicely, but if there's already an input provided (outside range), there's no invalidation at all. Triggering a change at init would fix the date, but I'd rather have the other approach: forcing user to fix this (so use some error visual, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

One option is to remove the ability to manually enter a date by making the input fields `readonly`. This will restrict the user from manually entering anything crazy, and forces the use of the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is re-set the date with entered one to trigger datepicker's internal checks. By comparing the old value and new one you can check if date is changed:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  maxDate: "+1",
  showOtherMonths: true}).on('change', function(e) {
        var oldDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (oldDate.getTime() !== newDate.getTime()){
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
```