# how to validate only one years of dates in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate within one years months and dates, and i created to allow only one year of dates but its not validated.

For example

Im created with in one year, Current date is 7/11/2019, i can allowed to pick date upto 7/11/2020, thats im created working fine.. but if i enter some date in manually its allowed. example: if i enter (type manually) 1/1/2022 its allowed.. i dont want to allow overthan 1 year dates.. how to validate this??

hope my question is understand..

Example Fiddle here..

**[FIDDLE HERE..](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/rw9tb7fp/)**

Example code here..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vochDate, #refdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate: '1y',
    minDate: "-10m"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group col-4 rfdate">
  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label p-sm-0" for="vouchdt">Voucher Date :</label>
  <div class="input-group vcdate datepic" id="vocdate">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vochDate" name="vouchdt" th:field="*{strvouchdt}" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `onchage` as => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228689/manual-date-entry-validation-for-jquery-ui-datepicker-maxdate-option

Comment: @DevsiOdedra please check this, its not working maybe - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/s9a1qcLt/

Comment: because maxDate is invalid thats why comparison doe not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have change in your code, see below answer.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vochDate, #refdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate: '1y',
    minDate: "-10m"
  });
    
  $(document).on( ' input change', '#vochDate', function(){
      $('.err').remove();
      const nr_years = 1;
      var maxDate = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + nr_years));
        var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        if (curDate > maxDate) {
            //alert("invalid date");
            $('#vochDate').after('<span class="err"> Invalid Date </span>');
            $(this).datepicker("setDate",  new Date());
            
        }
         
   })
});
```

```css
.err {
color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-group col-4 rfdate">
  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label p-sm-0" for="vouchdt">Voucher Date :</label>
  <div class="input-group vcdate datepic" id="vocdate">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vochDate" name="vouchdt" th:field="*{strvouchdt}" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! how can i show error message in html like,  invalide date please select valid date like..

Comment: if i select wrong data, error will come okay.. but why the maxDate showing in the field?

Comment: if noe max date, then which date you want to put when someone enter wrong date ? And if it helpful then accept so someone who need can refer it.

Comment: if someone enter wrong date, show error and comes to current date

Comment: ok , display error and make date field  blank or any date to fill ?

Answer (score 0):

Use change event to validate on change. Here you can have a look

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vochDate, #refdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    maxDate: '1y',
    minDate: "-10m"
  });
  $("#vochDate").change(function(){
    if((new Date($("#vochDate").val()).getTime()-new Date().getTime())/(1000*3600*24)>365){
    alert("invalid")
    //
    }
  })
});
```